# Django app deployed on Heroku is painfully slow on Firefox & Safari - potential causes?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, heroku

I've deployed an e-commerce site app to Heroku with the static files and media photos being hosted from an Amazon S3 bucket.

The app is totally smooth on Chrome and Brave (both mobile / desktop), but tends to be appallingly slow on Firefox and Safari, regardless of device.

As an example, here's a screenshot of how long some of the assets took to load when opening the app via Firefox.

Project link: [MyShop](https://varunbkk-myshop.herokuapp.com/)

[image]

If I run the project on local machine (also with static & media assets being loaded from S3 directly), it is still quite slow, albeit to a lesser degree.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Pretty hard to say without any details. You say it's slow locally, too, so this is unlikely to be entirely a Heroku problem.

Comment: I reduced the file sizes of the images, but the problem still persists on Firefox and Safari. At my wits end here.